# I am getting exhausted Resultset exceptin in mybatis while setting parameters

Tags: java, mybatis

i am getting Exhausted Resultset error. I am retrieving large data from db.
The Exhaused resut set error happens when retrieving a large amount of data. When the result is small set, it works fine.
Here is my code:

OfferStackability.java

```
  @Override
  public void loadOfferStackability(Collection<Offer> offers) {

   if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(offers)) {
        return;
    }

    Map<Long, Offer> offersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Offer offer : offers) {
        offersMap.put(offer.getId(), offer);
    }

    List<OfferStackability> offerStackabilities = offerStackabilityMapper.selectOffersStackability(new ArrayList<>(offersMap.keySet()));
    }}
```

OfferStackability.xml

```
<select id="selectOffersStackability" parameterType="list" resultMap="OfferStackability" timeout="10000">
    SELECT
    OFFER_STACKABILITY_ID, OFFER_ID, STACKED_OFFER_ID, IS_EXTERNAL, created_by, modified_by
    FROM
    offer_app.OFFER_STACKABILITY
    WHERE
    OFFER_ID
    IN
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
<resultMap id="OfferStackability" type="OfferStackability">
    <result property="id" column="OFFER_STACKABILITY_ID"/>
    <result property="offerId" column="OFFER_ID" />
    <result property="stackedId" column="STACKED_OFFER_ID" />
    <result property="isExternal" column="IS_EXTERNAL" />
    <result property="createdBy" column="created_by" />
    <result property="modifiedBy" column="modified_by" />
</resultMap>
```

Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

#### The error may exist in file [/home/tomcat/services/ofrs-1.0.0-1064483-v-1/webapps/ofrs_1.0.0-1064483/WEB-INF/classes/com/cobalt/services/offers/config/mybatis/mappers/OfferStackabilityMapper.xml]

#### The error may involve com.cobalt.services.offers.dao.mybatis.mappers.OfferStackabilityMapper.selectOffersStackability-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

Comment: plz show your pojo class which match with resultMap.

Comment: Please improve the content of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask